# Installing SVN on server

Tags: svn

I'm trying to install Python, SVN, Django, OSQA on GoDaddy using SSH. I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.techgeekguy.com/how-to-install-python-svn-django-osqa-web-hosting-server-hostmonster-dreamhost-bluehost-godaddy-hostgator/). However, I'm getting stuck on the SVN part. When I do all the details and check if the SVN was installed correctly, it tells me that the directory or file exists. To be clear, the command that I execute when it tells me that is:

```
cd
./svn/bin/svn --version
```

I tried to check if SVN has a directory named `bin`, but there isn't one. I created the SVN directory in the Python directory and then executed these commands in the SVN directory:

```
wget http://subversion.tigris.org/downloads/subversion-1.6.15.tar.bz2
wget http://subversion.tigris.org/downloads/subversion-deps-1.6.15.tar.bz2
tar -xjf subversion-1.6.15.tar.bz2
tar -xjf subversion-deps-1.6.15.tar.bz2
```

Next I executed these commands in the same directory:

```
cd subversion-1.6.15
./configure -prefix=$HOME/svn -with-expat=builtin -with-pic -with-ssl
make && make install
```

Then I tried checking to see if I installed SVN successfully, however, there isn't a directory named bin in SVN so that is why I'm getting an error saying the directory or file does not exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would anyone use SVN at this century? :)

Comment: @Nabin I'm a beginner, so I'm just following the tutorial to install Django on my GoDaddy hosting. I was trying to install it using `pip install` but it tells me that pip isn't a valid command

Comment: Try this *sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev*

Comment: @Nabin It says sudo command not found

Comment: May be you don't have full privilege

Comment: @Nabin Do you know how I can get full privilege?

Answer (score 0):

You must not use Subversion 1.7 or older versions. They don't receive security and bug fix updates and are out of support. BTW, the tutorial you follow is very outdated, too. I would recommend that you find another tutorial if you need one.